# Date formatter crash in swift

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

Please help me to modify this part of code,

```
if let dateVaule = UserDefaults().value(forKey: SplashSeenDate){
            let dateStr  = dateVaule as! String
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.ReferenceType.local
            let date = dateFormatter.date(from:dateStr)
            if Global.sharedInstance.Splashs != nil && Global.sharedInstance.Splashs?.count != 0{

                for (i,splash) in (Global.sharedInstance.Splashs?.enumerated().reversed())!{
                    if !checkTimeStamp(date: splash.create_timestamp,StoredDate: date!){
                        Global.sharedInstance.Splashs?.remove(at: i)
                    }
                }
                print(Global.sharedInstance.Splashs?.count ?? "-1")
            }
        }
```

Honestly speaking, i am very confuse with the date formatter.
when this project launch, it occured crash at

```
if !checkTimeStamp(date: splash.create_timestamp,StoredDate: date!){
```

However, I could not replicate this crash... **Only a few user with iOS10 occured this crash.**Please kindly advise, Thanks a lot!

```
func checkTimeStamp(date: String!,StoredDate: Date) -> Bool {
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier:"en_US_POSIX")
    let datecomponents = dateFormatter.date(from: date)

    if (datecomponents! >= StoredDate) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for reversing the array when enumerating through it?  Also, is it possible the array `Global.sharedInstance.Splashs` may be changing while looping through it?

Comment: @WilliamGP   If i am not do in reverse way, "Index out of range" will occur right after if any element removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are converting `String` to `Date` in two different ways:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.ReferenceType.local //###Why don't you use `TimeZone.current`?
let date = dateFormatter.date(from:dateStr)
```

And in `checkTimeStamp(date: String!,StoredDate: Date) -> Bool`:

```
let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier:"en_US_POSIX")
let datecomponents = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
```

In your case, **lacking this line is critical** for your first conversion:

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

You can find many articles discussing about `DateFormatter` (or `NSDateFormatter` in old articles) returning `nil`.

When you use `DateFormatter` with fixed format like `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"`, you must set `locale` to `Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")`.

Maybe you'd better define one conversion method (or computed property) to convert `String` to `Date` which fits for your app's requirements, and use it everywhere you need `String` to `Date` conversion:

```
extension String {
    var toAppDate: Date? {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") //### <- Do not miss.
        return dateFormatter.date(from: self)
    }
}
```

---

Generally, your code uses too much forced-unwrapping or forced-casting. You can re-write it without using any forced-something:

```
    if
        let dateStr = UserDefaults().string(forKey: SplashSeenDate),
        let date = dateStr.toAppDate,
        let splashes = Global.sharedInstance.Splashs, !splashes.isEmpty
    {
        //### In most cases, `filter` is faster than repeated `remove`.
        Global.sharedInstance.Splashs = splashes.filter {
            checkTimeStamp(date: $0.create_timestamp, storedDate: date)
        }
        print(Global.sharedInstance.Splashs?.count ?? "-1")
    }
```

(Assuming `create_timestamp` is not Optional, and renamed parameter label `StoredDate:` to `storedDate:`.)

Comment: Great! Clear and understandable. Thanks men!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `splash.create_timestamp` is getting nil and when you are passing in this function `checkTimeStamp`. It is getting crash. You can prevent the crash by changing date parameter inside checkTimeStamp function as optional and use guard statement before passing inside the function.